# How to download GNU COBOL 2016 and how does it work?

Tags: gnucobol

From what I understood from my researches is that GNU COBOL is a compiler and the input file has to be run under this compiler from the prompt command but what I have a hard time with is the right installation of GNU COBOL

Comment: Project webspace is on SourceForge.  Ask there for help.  In the meanwhile the GnoCOBOL FAQ has install instructions for quite a few operating environments.  http://open-cobol.sourceforge.net/faq/index.html#how-do-i-install-gnucobol

Answer (score 1):

Moving a comment to an answer for completeness.

Project webspace is on SourceForge. Ask there for help. In the meanwhile the GnuCOBOL FAQ has install instructions for quite a few operating environments. open-cobol.sourceforge.net/faq/index.html or avoiding a link, bing on google for "How do I install GnuCOBOL" and pick the entry that starts with GnuCOBOL FAQ.